# Python - how to get instance data from one class and use it in a second class method

Tags: python

I am new to OOP.

I have a problem because I would like to use the jira_user instance (login credentials) in the second Window2 class in the take_data function.

My problem is that Window2 view gets overwritten with Window1 view when I call `take_data()`. I understand this may be caused by `__init__` from Window1. I tried to use staticmethod, but the problem occurred when getting login data from Entry fields (`self.email_entry.get()`, `self.token_entry.get()`) did not have access to it.

I would like to be able to login to the Jira account in the first Window1 window (and it works correctly), then in the second Window2 window it would be possible to download data regarding cases (the take_csd_data function itself works correctly)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox as m_box
from test import Logowanie
import re


class Window1:
def __init__(self, master):
    self.master = master
    self.master.geometry('500x400')
    self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
    self.label = tk.Label(self.master, text='Logowanie', fg='blue', font='Helvetica 16 bold italic')
    self.label.place(x = 190, y = 100)
    self.button1 = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Log In', width = 25, command = self.new_window).grid(padx = 20, pady = 300)
    self.token_label = tk.Label(self.master, text='Token')
    self.token_label.place(x = 120, y = 197)
    self.email_label = tk.Label(self.master, text='E-mail')
    self.email_label.place(x = 120, y = 147)
    self.token_entry = tk.Entry(self.master, width = 25)
    self.token_entry.place(x = 175, y = 200)
    self.email_entry = tk.Entry(self.master, width = 25)
    self.email_entry.place(x = 175, y = 150)
    self.frame.pack()
    self.jira_user = None

def userLogin(self):
    self.jira_user = Logowanie('url.atlassian.net/', self.email_entry.get(),
                               self.token_entry.get())
    print('LogIn')
    return self.jira_user

def new_window(self):
    self.regex = r'\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,}\b'
    if(re.fullmatch(self.regex, self.email_entry.get())):
        self.userLogin()
        self.master.withdraw()
        self.toplevel = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        Window2(self.toplevel)
    else:
        m_box.showerror('Error','Błędny email')

class Window2():
def __init__(self, master):
    self.master = master
    self.master.geometry('500x400')
    self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
    self.quitButton = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Take Data From Jira', width = 25, command = self.take_data)
    self.quitButton.pack()
    self.frame.pack()

def take_data(self):
    self.a = Window1(self.master)
    self.a.userLogin().take_csd_data()


def main():
root = tk.Tk()
app = Window1(root)
root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

test.py

```
from jira import JIRA

class Logowanie():

def __init__(self, adres, mail, token):

    self.server_url = {'server': adres}
    self.auth_jira = JIRA(self.server_url, basic_auth=(mail, token))
    allfields = self.auth_jira.fields()
    self.nameMap = {self.auth_jira.field['name']:self.auth_jira.field['id'] for self.auth_jira.field in allfields}

def take_csd_data(self):

    for i in self.auth_jira.search_issues(jql_str='project = "Customer Service Desk"', maxResults=100):
        if str(i.fields.issuetype) == 'RMA' and str(i.fields.status) == 'Pending':
            print(f'Numer: {i.key} temat sprawy: {i.fields.summary} komponent: '
                  f'{i.fields.components} przypisana do:  {i.fields.assignee} '
                  f'{getattr(i.fields, self.nameMap["Quantity"])}')
```

I would appreciate any help or tips on how to solve this. Perhaps I do not fully understand working with Python classes.

Comment: What's the error you get? Or the actual problem in other words. You don't need staticmethod, is fine to pass object instances to instances of other classes and call their methods etc. like you are already doing.

Comment: The problem is that when I log in by entering the appropriate e-mail and token, another window (Window2) with the Take Data From Jira button is displayed to me. After clicking Take Data, it overwrite the entire View from the Window1 class.
I would like to take the login data from the userLogin method without the view that is in Window1 __init__.